# How to sftp into a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, sftp, filezilla

I've recently changed my OS from OS X to Ubuntu, which means that I can no longer use the desktop GitHub app. This is a problem because I host my website off GitHub and I need a way of uploading lots of different files, for example .jars, onto my website repository; I used to just use the desktop app to do this but I'm not really sure how to without it. I thought maybe I could use filezilla to sftp into the repository and upload it from there but I don't know how I'd do that. Is it possible?

Comment: If all else fails, you can use the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try out the SmartGit Linux client.  I've had some colleagues use it on Linux and really like it.
http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

To answer your question, SFTP into Git isn't supported that I'm aware of.  SSH into Git is a little more common, so you could also look into that route.

Comment: SmartGit seems a little complicated in the way that I need to install Git and also it costs. Do you know how to ssh into a repository?

Comment: It's explained here pretty well.  https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

Comment: I just found this article too.  I didn't know you could do this stuff from the command line.  Very cool!  https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/796387-beginning-git-and-github-for-linux-users/

Answer (score 3):

> I need a way of uploading lots of different files, for example .jars, onto my website repository;

You actually needs to `commit` and `push` the data. If you are using github, you should learn at least basics and not rely on some app.

There is nothing like "ssh to github" nor sftp. Github is GIT repository and the only thing you can do with it is to `clone`/`pull` and `push`.

Or if you are interested in the [desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/), it might work under `wine`?

Comment: I've found another app which I can use instead of the github one, called Git Kraken